# MongoDB remove the lowest score, node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to remove the lowest homework score.

I tried this,

```
var a = db.students.find({"scores.type":"homework"}, {"scores.$":1}).sort({"scores.score":1})
```

but how can I remove this set of data?

I have 200 pieces of similar data below.

```
{
    "_id" : 148,
    "name" : "Carli Belvins",
    "scores" : [
        {
            "type" : "exam",
            "score" : 84.4361816750119
        },
        {
            "type" : "quiz",
            "score" : 1.702113040528119
        },
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 22.47397850465176
        },
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 88.48032660881387
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: do you want to remove subdocument or any document

Comment: i want to remove subdocument, @MuhammadAli

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework question from MongoDB University.

Comment: @JohnPetrone i am a newbie and I tried to read documents to complete the homework. yet, i worked several hours and still have no idea how to finish it. That's why im trying to ask the question here. It's fine that you voted down without helping!

Comment: @JohnPetrone and i am not asking for the exact solution, i was trying to know how to solve the problem. I guess I am much better than others who don't try to learn or work hard.

Comment: You have to do that on 2 steps. First find the min score for each student. Then remove the min item from the array (you can use the $pull update operator for that), for each student.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to remove an element but the statement you provided is just to find it.

Use  `db.students.remove(<query>)` instead. Full documentation [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/)

Comment: I know the remove() method, however, it doesn't work for this case.

Comment: so i think you should first get the id of the student with max score db.students.find({"scores.type":"homework"}).sort({'scores.score':-1}).limit(1) and remove the entity by id using the remove method.

Comment: but you need to remove a specific score and not the whole entity so you should get the entity by id and remove the lowest score using the $pull operator.